# How to do association fetching with restrictions in hibernate 4?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have root entity `Hostel` and its single association `User owner`.

When I fetch `Hostel` entity I need to eagerly fetch `User owner`, but only owner's 3 properties : `userId`,`firstName`,`lastName`.

Moreover, in this query I need not fetch some associations of `User owner`. They are : `avatar` and `images` of `User` entity.

For now my criteria query is :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void findHostelBy(HostelSearch hs) {
        Criteria criteria = currenSession().createCriteria(Hostel.class);

        String country = hs.getCountry();

        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("endDate", Calendar.getInstance()));
        if (StringUtils.notNullAndEmpty(country)) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("country", country));
        }

        // making Hostel's associations lazy
        criteria.setFetchMode("images", FetchMode.SELECT);
        criteria.setFetchMode("requests", FetchMode.SELECT);
        criteria.setFetchMode("feedbacks", FetchMode.SELECT);

        criteria.setReadOnly(true);
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("rating"));

        // retrieve owner association
        criteria = criteria
                .createAlias("owner","owner",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
                .setProjection(
                        Projections.projectionList()
                                .add(Projections.property("owner.userId"))
                                .add(Projections.property("owner.firstName"))
                                .add(Projections.property("owner.lastName")))
                .setFetchMode("owner.avatar", FetchMode.SELECT)
                .setFetchMode("owner.images", FetchMode.SELECT);

        Long count = (Long) criteria
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                .setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();

        criteria.setProjection(null);

        List<Hostel> hostels = criteria.list();

        for (Hostel hostel : hostels) {
            User owner = hostel.getOwner();
            System.out.println("owner=" + owner);
        }           
    }
```

After `// retrieve owner association` comments I do fetching of `User owner` association. I restrict select of `owner` to 3 properties by:

```
Projections.projectionList()
                                .add(Projections.property("owner.userId"))
                                .add(Projections.property("owner.firstName"))
                                .add(Projections.property("owner.lastName")))
```

Then I make owner's associations avatar and images to be lazy:

```
.setFetchMode("owner.avatar", FetchMode.SELECT)
.setFetchMode("owner.images", FetchMode.SELECT);
```

I get exception on line

```
List<Hostel> hostels = criteria.list();
```

The exception is :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.home.hostme.entity.Image. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1092)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1019)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1107)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at com.home.hostme.dao.impl.HostelDaoImpl.findHostelBy(HostelDaoImpl.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    ... 51 more
```

Primary key column of root `Hostel` entity is Integer but primary key of `Image` entity is Long. But I don't want to retrieve `avatar` or `images` eagerly from `User owner` and I described it.

How to update my query to lazily fetch `avatar` and `images` from `User owner` association?

This query fetches all properties from `User owner` association so my Restrictions do not work as well.

p.S. If I don't fetch `User owner` association then all is working ok.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you instruct Hibernate about a LAZY fetch:

```
.setFetchMode("owner.avatar", FetchMode.SELECT)
```

FetchMode.SELECT is for retrieving the associated info in a a separate select

For LAZY, you should set:

```
.setFetchMode("owner.avatar", FetchMode.LAZY)
```

also there are so many idoms I don't really get, like:

1. Why do you create a projection to get a count:

   ```
   Long count = (Long) criteria
           .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
           .setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
   ```
2. Then set the projection to null

   ```
   criteria.setProjection(null);
   ```

If you want a list of Hostels with owners but without any other associations, you can simply mark those with:

```
.setFetchMode("owner.avatar", FetchMode.LAZY)
```

Another option is to have all associations LAZY and simply instruct what to fetch on a query basis:

```
select h
from Hostel h
left join fetch h.owner o
```

While h.owner.avatar and h.owner.images make sense not to be fetched, h.owner.hostel is the actual hostel reference and Hibernate won't issue a new join for that two. It knows how to handle bidirectional associations with a single join.

Comment: isn't FetchMode.LAZY deprecated? refer:https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/FetchMode.html